# duplicate class definition error with derby / openjdk-6

Tags: derby, java

Im getting the following exception when attempting to connect to a derby server via openjpa:
`attempted duplicate class definition for name: "sun/security/pkcs11/SunPKCS11"`. Looking through some google results it looks like theres a known problem with java on mac, but im using ubuntu, and openjdk-6. Im really not sure where to start solving this. Anyone any ideas whats going wrong?

`java -version` output:

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.1) (6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

Error stack trace (lengthy...)

```
Exception in thread "main" <openjpa-2.2.0-r422266:1244990 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There were errors initializing your configuration: java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  sun/misc/Launcher$ExtClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "sun/security/pkcs11/SunPKCS11"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:314)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$3.run(ProviderConfig.java:253)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$3.run(ProviderConfig.java:244)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.doLoadProvider(ProviderConfig.java:244)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.getProvider(ProviderConfig.java:224)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.loadAll(ProviderList.java:281)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.removeInvalid(ProviderList.java:298)
    at sun.security.jca.Providers.getFullProviderList(Providers.java:170)
    at java.security.Security.getProviders(Security.java:457)
    at java.security.Security.getProviders(Security.java:607)
    at java.security.Security.getProviders(Security.java:552)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.EncryptionManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientBaseDataSource.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver.tokenizeURLProperties(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.DBCPDriverDataSource.getDBCPConnection(DBCPDriverDataSource.java:74)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.AutoDriverDataSource.getConnection(AutoDriverDataSource.java:42)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.SimpleDriverDataSource.getConnection(SimpleDriverDataSource.java:75)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingDataSource.getConnection(DelegatingDataSource.java:118)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DecoratingDataSource.getConnection(DecoratingDataSource.java:93)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.DataSourceFactory.installDBDictionary(DataSourceFactory.java:233)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.getConnectionFactory(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:733)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.ConfigurationImpl.instantiateAll(ConfigurationImpl.java:295)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.instantiateAll(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:1671)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.makeReadOnly(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:646)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:203)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:227)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:154)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:60)
    at org.dynamosoftware.jpatest.App.main(App.java:15)
```

Comment: Is the exception happening in your application? Or in the Derby server? This sounds like a classpath problem, possibly aggravated by the fact that JDK 1.6 tries to auto-load JDBC drivers in automatic ways. Possibly using -verbose:class will give you more clues.

Comment: Nope, its from my app, i can start the derby server no problem, its when i attempt to connect through openjpa that i run into problems. The method thats actually falling over is a derby method however (edited question with stack trace)

Comment: What happens if, using the same CLASSPATH that you use to run your application, you run some very simple code like: http://theblasfrompas.blogspot.com/2009/02/determine-th-security-providers-for-jvm.html